# MYSQL: show registers, relate and rename

Tags: mysql

The instructions are the following:

Generate a report of all the products purchased by the customers where it appears: the id of the customer, the customer's full name, the city, the state, the ID number, the date of sale, the product code, the product name, the quantity sold and finally a message that says "you paid" or "payment Pending" status depending on the payment status where 0 = paid and 1 = pending. This report should appear sorted alphabetically first by state and then by customer name.

what I tried is this:

```
    select cli_nom, cli_city, cli_state, fac_num, fac_saledate, prod_cod, fac_total, fac_status 
where fac_status = 0 as paid and fac_status = 1 as pending 
from factures, products, clients order by cli_state, cli_nom, asc;
```

Wich absolutley didnt work, Im not sure about the sintax to rename or mask a column.

The table structures are the following:

```
table clientes:

 1. cli_nom  varchar(100)
 2. cli_state varchar(100)
 3. cli_city varchar(100)
 4. cli_id int(11)
 5. cli_status int(11)
 6. cli_dateofsale date

table products:

 1. prod_cod int(11)
 2. prod_categ char(1)
 3. prod_nom varchar(100)
 4. prod_price double
 5. prod_descrip varchar(100)
 6. prod_discount float

table facturas:

 1. fac_num int(11)
 2. fac_datesold date
 3. fac_cli_id int(11)
 4. fac_status int
 5. fac_total float
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to explain what the problem is with your current query (expected result vs actual result). Including a table structure and some sample data usually helps too. You are expected to help us help you. Please note, if this is a school assignment, your teacher is expecting **you** to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed a school assignment, but my teacher hasnt assisted in two weeks and Im trying to keep my grades high even when I havent been provided with any studying material, but these excercises. 
I'll try now to edit the question and add the table structures, hope It doesnt look messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a trouble with the querys.
When you want to query something, the form of the complete statement is something like this

```
Select [fields]
from [table(s)] --which means there includes inner joins
where [filter rows]
group by [fields to group]
having [filtering groups]
order by [fields]
```

Of course, is something much more complicated and bigger than this, but it will give you some initial concepts.

You will always have to respect this order, so in your query are putting a where into the select.

If you want to change something to show, dependending on some evaluation, but you will ALWAYS show something (you are not filtering, you are choosing what to show according to the value), you can use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) clause.

In this example, you could do something like this

```
select cli_nom, cli_city, cli_state, fac_num, fac_saledate, 
prod_cod, fac_total, fac_status 
CASE when fac_status = 0  then 'You Paid'
     when fac_status = 1 then 'payment Pending'
     else 'Not sure about state' END
from factures
inner join products on --put here how do you relate products with factures
inner join clients on -- put here how do you relate clients with products/factures
order by cli_state, cli_nom, asc;
```

If you don't know how to use INNER JOIN, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html) you have some info.

Basically, is a clause that is used to relate two tables.

something like

```
(..)
from Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B on A.id = B.id
```

(A and B are aliases, and representing the table that have set).

This means that it will compare every row from Table1 to every row from Table2, and when the condition is matched (in this case id from table1 [`A.id`] equals id from Table2 [`= B.id]`) then that relation-row is showed (means that it will show you all the row from table1 + all the row from table2)

Comment: Omg thank you so much, I didnt know about the using of "case" on mysql. ^_^

Comment: hope it solves your problems! If this helps you and answer your question, don't forget about upvote and tick it as correct answer :)